# What is this three-bladed vintage aircraft?

Tags: military, propeller, aircraft-identification, fighter

We found this poster at IKEA, [EDELVIK Poster 103.776.29](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/10377629/).

[image]

[Allposters.com](http://www.allposters.com/-sp/Dramatic-Scene-on-the-Sky-Vintage-Fighter-Plane-Inbound-from-Sun-Posters_i10863338_.htm) has another poster, which includes the same aircraft, but 2 in formation, possibly the same original photo/artist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a North American T-28 Trojan, a postwar era military aircraft used for basic flight training an the Navy and Marine Corps.

[image]

They still remain popular with warbird collectors and enthusiasts.

Comment: That was the closest match I did find, but wasn't sure.  All the photos of t-28's I find have the air scoops at the 12 o'clock and 5 o'clock.  The poster is 12 and 7?

Comment: @ChadWright the image in the poster could have been mirrored. In fact the poster with 2 in formation are mirrored from each other.

Comment: @fooot, just noticed that in the second poster.  Thanks, mystery solved!

Comment: That is a fine looking aircraft!